# what is the significance of crossing the Potomac river in the following excerpt?

Tags: meaning

Over the last 40 years, Mattis said, there had been some years when relations between the secretary of state and secretary of defense had been so bad they did not speak to each other or even so much as cross the Potomac River and shake hands.

what I guess is that they would cross the Potomac river but not shake hands because of their bad relationship. Can anybody tell me its significance?

Comment: Obviously, they couldn't shake hands if they were on opposite sides of the river (and, one assumes, quite a lot further apart). ' ... they did not even shake hands' invites the riposte "Well, how could they when they were miles apart?" Crossing a large river (plus all the other necessary travelling) just to spend 5 seconds shaking hands stretches credulity. ' ... they did not even so much as cross the Potomac River and shake hands' pre-empts the riposte, and disguises the stupidity of the 6 h journeying for a 5 second handshake by invoking humour.

Comment: thank you very much.

Comment: The Potomac River splits Washington DC from Arlington VA.   The White House is in Washington while the Pentagon is in Arlington.

Answer (score 3):

The Potomac River splits Washington DC from Arlington VA. The White House is on the east side of the river in Washington while the Pentagon is on the west side in Arlington.

The Secretary of State's office is located in the Truman Building, about a half-mile west of the White House.  This is on the east side of the Potomac.  The Secretary of Defense's office is located in the Pentagon, on the west side of the Potomac.  To see each other face-to-face (and not on Zoom) one of the pair would have to cross the Potomac.

The statement by Mattis is implying that there were times when neither individual felt it was worthwhile to make the journey.

Answer (score -2):

There is more to this than literal meaning.

> Here is a brief introduction:
>
> "Background – Centuries of Dispute
> Maryland and Virginia have bickered over control of the Potomac River since the 1700s. The roots of the dispute reach even farther back in time: Virginia’s claims go back to a 1609 charter from King James I and a 1688 patent from King James II, both of which included the Potomac. Maryland’s claim dates to a 1632 charter from King Charles I, which also included the Potomac. In its 1776 constitution Virginia recognized the validity of the 1632 charter, but reserved the rights of “navigation and use” of the Potomac. Maryland’s constitutional convention shortly afterward passed a resolution rejecting Virginia’s reservation." {there is much more in the link}
>
> [National Sea Grant Law Centre](http://nsglc.olemiss.edu/SandBar/SandBar2/2.4supreme.htm)

The dispute continues into modern times. I therefore believe that the two secretaries would not shake hands because their disputes were deep and long-standing, in the same way that the old acrimonious Potomac dispute has not been resolved to the present day